# In azure can multiple web apps perform CRUD operations on the same data

Tags: azure, web

In azure I have a few web apps running using the same database.

But the data never clashes or anything; it's like azure has partitioned the database somehow.

I would like two web apps under different domains to access the same data with a separate api project.

What is the best way to configure this project in azure?

And in visual studio? Can I have them all in the same solution and publish them to the right place?

Comment: The best way is to share a common library that access the Database. (using the ORM you like)
In visual studio, you would have 1 solution with 2 webApi project that publish on your different webAps. 
About the concurrency concern, and if you use EntityFW, check out http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/handling-concurrency-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Azure, you should setup one Azure SQL Database and multiple API Apps / Web Apps that all use the same connection string pointing to that database.

In Visual Studio, the best way to configure it depends on a couple of things.

1. If the WebAPIs are exactly the same just with a different domain

You can setup multiple publish profiles for a single Web Application Project. These publish profiles can tie to different release configurations which can transform things in your web.config to account for the differing domains. This is particularly important when using SSL, authentication or something like that.

2. If the WebAPIs are different for each domain

In this case, you will likely have different projects for each distinct WebAPI. You can have them all in one solution or separate solutions. It might be easier to setup different solutions if you want to enable automated build using Visual Studio Online or something as the Visual Studio build task keys off the *.sln file and if you have multiple Web Application projects in one solution your build outputs will be mixed up which can cause some issues when deploying.